# MVC AJAX returns only partial view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Trying to get this AJAX form to update the tbody of a table but the browser submits to the controller returning only the partial view.  I think all javascript files mentioned in other posts are referenced correctly.  The following code is from a test application that can be forwarded if needed.

This form should change the data in the table to 8 rows instead of 4 when the checkbox is checked, but it doesn't update the table and only returns the contents of the partial view with the 8 rows.

Main View (Index.cshtml):

```
@{
AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "notesTableBody",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
};
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("NotesPartial", options))
{
    <h3 class="csgOrange ib" style="margin-top:-20px;">Notes |</h3> <span class="f14">@Html.CheckBox("ShowMoreNotes") Show More Notes</span>
    <input type="hidden" id="num" name="num" value="8" />
}

<table class="table table-striped tableAutoWidth">
    <tr>
        <th>NoteID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Text</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="notesTableBody">
        @Html.Action("NotesPartial", new { num = 4 })
    </tbody>

</table>

@section Scripts {

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ShowMoreNotes').click(function () {
            this.form.submit();
        });

    });

</script>
```

}

Partial View (NotesPartial.cshtml):

```
@model IEnumerable<TestAJAX.Models.NoteViewModel>
@foreach (TestAJAX.Models.NoteViewModel note in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => note.NoteID)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => note.Title)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => note.Text)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Controller for table contents:

```
 public PartialViewResult NotesPartial(int num)
    {
        IList<NoteViewModel> noteList = new List<NoteViewModel>();

        for (int i=0; i<num; i++)
        {
            noteList.Add(new NoteViewModel { NoteID = i, Title = "Title " + i, Text = "Note text " + i });
        }

        return PartialView(noteList);
    }
```

The javascript file references are handled in the layout.  Here's what they look like after they're rendered.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
```

Comment: The scripts you have shown here are correct. Are you sure you have not included a duplicate anywhere, and that javascript is enabled in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  It has to do with the way the form is submitted.  I had to give the AJAX form an id:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("NotesPartial", "Home", options, new { id = "NotesForm" }))
```

Then I was able to submit the form this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ShowMoreNotes').click(function () {
            //this.form.submit();
            $('#NotesForm').submit();
        });

    });
```

Perhaps using this.form.submit() won't submit a form as an AJAX form.

Comment: `this` is the element with `id="ShowMoreNotes"` i.e. your checkbox, which does not contain a form